# Spark Sql column to filter is not accesible

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am wondering why this SQL statement is not working when I add the last filter :

```
where filter_col = True
```

and go error like  :

> AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`filter_col`' given input columns:
> [a.cnt_tiers, a.date, a.etat, a.max_date, a.pays, a.poid, a.tiers,
> a.zyada]; line 13 pos 32; 'Project ['a.tiers, 'a.poid, 'a.etat,
> 'a.pays, 'a.zyada, 'a.date, 'a.max_date, 'a.cnt_tiers, CASE WHEN
> ('a.cnt_tiers = 1) THEN true WHEN (('a.cnt_tiers > 1) AND ('a.date =
> 'a.max_date)) THEN true ELSE false END AS filter_col#15176]

```
dfsql = spark.sql(""" select a.tiers , a.poid, a.etat, a.pays , a.zyada, a.date , a.max_date ,a.cnt_tiers,
                     CASE
                          WHEN a.cnt_tiers  = 1 THEN True
                          WHEN a.cnt_tiers  > 1  and a.date =a.max_date THEN True 
                          ELSE False 
                      END AS filter_col    

                      from (select *,  MAX(date) OVER (PARTITION BY tiers) AS max_date , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY tiers) as cnt_tiers
                          
                          from tierstbl 
                          where poid is not null and   etat is not null  and  pays  is not null and zyada  is not null )  a 

                          where filter_col = True
                        
                          
    
  """)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can include the logic that evaluates to true in your where clause.

```
where
poid is not null
...
AND ((cnt_tiers  = 1 ) OR (a.cnt_tiers  > 1  and a.date =a.max_date))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `filter_col` column in inner table (`a`), it has only `cnt_tiers` column. If you need to filter based on filter_col, you need to nest another layer of select outside, or use case when in the inner table to **directly construct the filter_col column** instead of the cnt_tiers column.

Comment: puting the CASE/When inside (a) table is not working . can you show me how to nest another layer of select outside ?

Comment: Use your existing SQL as the inner table b, `select ... from (existing sql statement) b where filter_col is true`